# pandas data frames delta (subtraction)

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 non indexed data frames as follow:
df1

```
John   Mullen  12/08/1993
Lisa   Bush    06/12/1990
Maria  Murphy  30/03/1989
Seth   Black   21/06/1991
```

and df2

```
John   Mullen  12/08/1993
Lisa   Bush    06/12/1990
Seth   Black   21/06/1991    
Joe    Maher   28/09/1990
Debby  White   03/01/1992
```

I want to have a data delta, where only the records that are in df2 and not df1 will appear: i.e.

```
Joe    Maher   28/09/1990
Debby  White   03/01/1992
```

I there a way to achieve this?
I tried an inner join, but I couldn't find a way to subtract it from df2.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension together with `join` to create unique keys of each table consisting of the the first name, last name and the date field (I assumed date of birth).  Each field needs to be converted to a string if it is not already.

You then use another list comprehension together with `enumerate` to get the index location of each key in key2 that is not also in key1.

Finally, use `iloc` to get all rows in df2 based on the indexing from the previous step.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'First': {0: 'John', 1: 'Lisa', 2: 'Maria', 3: 'Seth'},
                    'Last': {0: 'Mullen', 1: 'Bush', 2: 'Murphy', 3: 'Black'},
                    'dob': {0: '12/08/1993', 1: '06/12/1990', 2: '30/03/1989', 3: '21/06/1991'}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'First': {0: 'John', 1: 'Lisa', 2: 'Seth', 3: 'Joe', 4: 'Debby'},
                    'Last': {0: 'Mullen', 1: 'Bush', 2: 'Black', 3: 'Maher', 4: 'White'},
                    'dob': {0: '12/08/1993', 1: '06/12/1990',  2: '21/06/1991',  3: '28/09/1990',  4: '03/01/1992'}})

key1 = ["".join([first, last, dob]) 
        for first, last, dob in zip(df1.First, df1.Last, df1.dob)]

key2 = ["".join([first, last, dob]) 
        for first, last, dob in zip(df2.First, df2.Last, df2.dob)]

idx = [n for n, k in enumerate(key2) 
       if k not in key1]

>>> df2.iloc[idx, :]
   First   Last         dob
3    Joe  Maher  28/09/1990
4  Debby  White  03/01/1992
```

Assuming you do not have any other columns in your dataframe, you could use `drop_duplicates` as suggested by @SebastianWozny.  However, you need to only select the new rows added (not `df1`).  You can do that as follows:

```
>>> df1.append(df2).drop_duplicates().iloc[df1.shape[0]:, :]
   First   Last         dob
3    Joe  Maher  28/09/1990
4  Debby  White  03/01/1992
```

Comment: I'm learning pandas right now. How did you create sample data so fast? Is it a well known example df?

Comment: In this case, `df1 = pd.read_clipboard(names=['First', 'Last', 'dob'])`.  BTW, I was about to upvote your response but you had deleted it.  I'll do so now. Oh, and then `df1.to_dict()` to get the dictionary representation.

Answer (score 1):

You can append the two frames and use `drop_duplicates` to get the unique rows, then as suggested by @Alexander you can use `iloc` to get the rows you want:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'First': {0: 'John', 1: 'Lisa', 2: 'Maria', 3: 'Seth'},
                    'Last': {0: 'Mullen', 1: 'Bush', 2: 'Murphy', 3: 'Black'},
                    'dob': {0: '12/08/1993', 1: '06/12/1990', 2: '30/03/1989', 3: '21/06/1991'}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'First': {0: 'John', 1: 'Lisa', 2: 'Seth', 3: 'Joe', 4: 'Debby'},
                    'Last': {0: 'Mullen', 1: 'Bush', 2: 'Black', 3: 'Maher', 4: 'White'},
                    'dob': {0: '12/08/1993', 1: '06/12/1990',  2: '21/06/1991',  3: '28/09/1990',  4: '03/01/1992'}})
>>> df1.append(df2).drop_duplicates()
   First    Last         dob
0   John  Mullen  12/08/1993
1   Lisa    Bush  06/12/1990
2  Maria  Murphy  30/03/1989
3   Seth   Black  21/06/1991
3    Joe   Maher  28/09/1990
4  Debby   White  03/01/1992
>>> df1.append(df2).drop_duplicates().iloc[df1.shape[0]:, :]
   First   Last         dob
3    Joe  Maher  28/09/1990
4  Debby  White  03/01/1992
```